# ProductVariantType form is declared final, so it can't be extended

Tags: php, sylius

After switching my installation to sylius beta 1, i noticed that some form classes like [this one](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/commit/f76433ea99ad44c5b0fea2d87d0142e9d0d9a0b1#diff-387bc7e94e80a4c3d22c2895f37f67cbR29) has been declared final, which makes then non extendable.

In our project we need to give the products admin the ability to set more information from the admin ui form. Before switch to beta we managed to do that extending that ProductVariantType form and overriding the related template. 
Now it looks ProductVariantType can't be extended anymore, so:

- Why this class have been made final again?
- Which should be the way to extend forms now? I can't see any other option than duplicating code.

Comment: To extend, you need to completely copy the file and change the service definition in the yml. 

I'm not sure what the reasoning was for making classes final

Comment: i found another way to do it more clean, i'd say. looks you can define kinda form extensions like this
`app.form.extension.type.product_variant:
        class: MyBundle\Form\Extension\ProductVariantTypeExtension

        tags:
             - {name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductVariantType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs (http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/form.html), we described there best practices for customizing forms.